# system hang with possible relevance to "clocksource tsc unstable"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

We've got half a dozen servers that randomly hang after several days of running. Checking the messages log I have observed they all have "clocksource tsc unstable" then "Time: acpi_pm clocksource has been installed". All these messages happened around a moment of system time adjustment by one of our applications that keeps server time in sync with a remote system once in a while. In each case, the server hangs within several hours after the "acpi_am" clocksource was installed.

We use the stime() function to set the system time directly.

I am kind of newbie to this kind of debugging but I am trying to get the sense of it by reading the tsc.c source code. Our kernel version is  2.6.23.8, cpu is Intel Core 2 Quad Q9400.

Is this a kernel bug ? Or it is a problem with the acpi_pm clocksource?

Edit 1: After git log search all the new changes related to "clocksource" in the current Linux kernel tree, it turns out there's a HUGE amount of changes regarding clocksources. This looks hard to track down an existing fix that might be the applicable to my problem.

Edit 2: Looks like I don't have HPET

```
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource  
tsc acpi_pm jiffies
```

Edit 3: Thanks @thkala. Description of the "hang" : I can still ping the server. Using telnet I can still probe out that common port like 21, 80 are still open. But SSH, VNC will "hang" ( no response from server ). Connecting a monitor to the server, the GUI can be seen with the mouse cursor, but the screen just freezes at the same picture. Connecting a usb optical mouse to the server, the red light would blink once and completely goes dark.. Connecting a usb keyboard, the caplock numlock all cannot light up.

Edit 4: As for the evidence. @thkala really got a good point. I checked all my 5 servers with the "hang" issue for their messages after forcing them to shutdown and reboot, no other abnormal messages except the "clocksource tsc unstable". The "tsc" log happened once during the particular boot session and in each case the hang happened AFTER the "acpi_pm" clocksource was installed. Some servers were up for many ~16 days and within 1 to 13 hours after "acpi_pm" installed, the server hang. Other servers didn't show this message and didn't hang.. You are right it's not conclusive but I have been digging in this direction based on speculation..

Anybody has an idea about this?

Comment: Your kernel version is ancient, that might be part of the problem … To be a bit more helpful, I also had this problem (the "clocksource tsc unstable" one) on a Core 1 a while ago and had to add "notsc" to the kernel command line.

Comment: The "proper" clocksource on your system should be HPET (I guess), is that one built into the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(I don't really like debugging via crystal-ball, but I'll give it a shot...)*

A few points of note:

1. You do not specify the exact meaning of *"hung"* in the context of your question. Does the kernel stop completely - or is it just your applications? Does it go to 100% CPU and stay there? Does it respond at all to any stimuli? Are there any related console messages at the time of the problem?
2. You do not mention how exactly you ended up with the clock & timing system as your suspect - *"within several hours"* is not exactly solid evidence. Have you ruled out hardware problems (including power fluctuations)? What else did you rule out and why?
3. Unstable clock sources are more common than you might think - from my own system:

   ```
   kernel: Marking TSC unstable due to TSC halts in idle
   ```
4. You are using a very old kernel - there have been several fixes related to the kernel locking up when the time is adjusted, such as the now famous [June 30, 2012 leap second issue](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7010351).
5. You seem to be suffering from [NIH syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) - using a custom application for time synchronization instead of [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) sounds like a recipe for disaster...

Comment: I don't really think anyone could pinpoint exactly what's wrong with this. Thanks for your hints and mark your answer now. :D